# Where does the Change Of Variable of Riemann-Stieltjes integral theorem uses continuity of COV function? Isn't the assumption superfluous? Apostol 7.7

Tags: continuity, change-of-variable, stieltjes-integral

Here is theorem 7.7 from Tom Apostol, Mathematical Analysis:

> Let $f\in \mathfrak R (\alpha)$ on $[a,b]$ and let $g$ be a strictly monotonic continuous function defined on an interval $S$ having enpoints $c$ and $d$. Assume that $a=g(c)$,$b=g(d)$. Let $h$ and $\beta$ be the composite functions defined as follows:
> $$h(x)=f[g(c)]$$
> $$ \beta (x)=\alpha [g(x)]$$,
> if $x\in S$.

> Then $h\in \mathfrak R (\beta )$ on $S$ and we have $\int_a ^b f d\alpha = \int_c ^d h d\beta $. That is,
> $$ \int_{g(c)} ^{g(d)} f(t) d\alpha (t) = \int_c ^d f[g(x)] d( \alpha [g(x)]) $$

And the proof:

[image: proof of change of variable in Riemann-Stieltjes]

### The question:

Do we really need to make the assumption that $g$ is continuous ?

Apostol says $g$ must be continuous, but I nowhere see he uses it in the proof.

In Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis, theorem $6.19$ on change of variable, it is the same: he states $g$ has to be continuous in the hypothesis, but I don't see the hypothesis used in the proof.

T.I.A.

Comment: The part "*then $g$ is one-to-one and has a strictly increasing, continuous inverse $g^{-1}$*" uses the hypothesis that $g$ is continuous. *Strictly monotonic* implies *injective* for any function, but it does not imply *surjective*, and therefore *one-to-one*, unless $g$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a theorem for an interval of monotonicity only, that is easy to prove.

In the general case the function has to be absolutely continuous, that is, it is the derivative of an integral.

And if it has (discrete points of ) discontinuouities, by additivity, its the sum over intervals of continuity.

Finally, the integral of a non strict monotone function has to be partitioned as a sum over monotone increasing, constant and monotone decreasing intervals.

All this is immediately transparent, if integration over $dy$ is used: Lebesgue integral   $\int y \ \mathbb{vol}( f^{-1}(dy) ))$ where the preimage of $dy$ automatically decomposes in coherent subsets of the real $x$-line. And all limits are trivial, including the fact that the integral can be formally extended to all of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When you say "in the general case the function has to be absolutely continuous", do you mean *in any cases* $g$ must be absolutely continuous **or** that *in the case where we don't place ourselves in an interval of montonicity* $g$ must be absolutely continuous ?

Comment: The selfreffering term "absolute continuity" is the final point of the evolution of expanding Riemann sums to the maximal set of function as its domain of convergence. Cantor studied Fourier sums as a tool to define functions with oscillations with a limit  point of shinking distances, that cannot be resolved by a Riemann sum. So absolute convergency of the Riemann sum is the critical point: If all values summed up take to be positive, all alternating Riemann sums with 1/n decay diverge, while the difference of positive and negative sum may converge,  results depend on sorting the series.